# What versions of DXA will be supported for older versions of Tridion?

Tags: web8, dxa, dxa-java, 2013-sp1-hr1, dxa-net

I need to plan the DXA and Tridion upgrade strategy for clients and I see that

> (*) SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 is only supported up to DXA version 1.6. in https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet

What versions of DXA are supported for each of the older versions of Tridion?
We have recently upgraded to HR1 in preparation for Web 8 upgrade, will DXA 2.0 be supported in 2013 HR1?

Comment: At this point in time there is no intention to support 2013 SP1 with DXA 2.0 - but given the expected community involvement in it, I'm not surprised if this changes.

Comment: As Jonathan mentions in his spot on answer, check out my [blog post](https://community.sdl.com/solutions/content-management/tridion/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/out-with-the-old-in-with-the-new), your upgrade strategy for DXA should contain an answer to the following question: is the value of a certain release enough to warrant the additional work to upgrade to that release? My job as the Product Manager for DXA will be to reduce the amount of additional work that is required for an upgrade as much as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Offically, DXA v1.6 is the last version that will be supported and fully tested against SDL Tridion 2013 SP1.

Bart covers this in detail in his [Out with the old, in with the new](https://community.sdl.com/solutions/content-management/tridion/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/out-with-the-old-in-with-the-new) post on the community site. In this post Bart outlines three options:

1. Upgrade to SDL Web 8
2. Continue to use the fully supported and tested DXA 1.6 version with Tridion 2013 SP1
3. Modify DXA 1.7 to compile against 2013 SP1

However, although this is the 'official' line, I'd be very surprised, given the number of (particularly DD4T) customers that are still using SDL Tridion 2013 SP1, if the 'merged' (DXA+DD4T) DXA v2.0 wasn't thoroughly tested against (but probably not supported for) SDL Tridion 2013 SP1. This is just my opinion though!

Comment: For DXA 2.0 we are not planning to create acceptance test scenarios for 2013 SP1, since we will already have to test on Web 8 CU1, Web 8.5 and SDL Web Cloud. That is three different versions, for both .NET and Java, equals 6 runs for each scenario. Neither are we planning to code in support for 2013 SP1 (i.e. support for older versions of third party libraries), so the likelyhood that it will work out of the box on 2013 SP1 is very low. As Nuno mentioned in his comment on the question, community involvement could make a change here.

Comment: Chris, Also worth a read are: https://community.sdl.com/solutions/content-management/tridion/b/weblog/posts/sdl-releases-the-sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-1-6 see:  _"DXA 1.6 is available for SDL Tridion 2013 SP1, SDL Web 8 CU1 and SDL Web Cloud, in both Java and .NET. DXA 1.6 will be the last version supporting SDL Tridion 2013 SP1, support for 2013 SP1 will be dropped in the next release."_   and https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v6/GUID-8EB06F10-1F31-4565-B051-A594BB264DA9

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Bart. I agree that we have to make a cut off somewhere and that the support has to be in line with SDL's standard policies. It's a good time to get all of those 2013 (and earlier) customers upgraded!

Comment: Indeed @JonathanWilliams, dropping (support for) something is never a popular thing to do, but still vital to the lifecycle.