# DXA 1.7 supports Tridion 2013 SP1?

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.7

Reading the [product prerequisites for DXA 1.7](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20DXA-v7&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-DD402008-D5C5-4DCA-A74F-893272D2B659&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-DD402008-D5C5-4DCA-A74F-893272D2B659.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-DD402008-D5C5-4DCA-A74F-893272D2B659) it's not clear if it only supports SDL Web 8, as it says:

DXA runs in combination with the following SDL product release:

- SDL Web 8 with Cumulative Update 1 applied

Comment: No, DXA 1.7 only supports Web 8.1.1 and 8.5

Comment: Possible duplicate? Please see http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/16075/71